# Two printers complete the job in 12 minutes; find the time it would take for each to complete the job alone

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

> It takes an HP LaserJet 1300 laser printer 10 minutes longer to complete a 600-page print job by itself than it takes an HP LaserJet 2420 to complete the same job by itself. Together the two printers can complete the job in 12 minutes. How long does it take each printer to complete the print job alone? What is the speed of each printer?

I know the time to complete the job for the 1300  is 10+x, because x is the time to complete the job for the 2420. I just don't understand what to do next.

Comment: There are a number of techniques for solving a [system of linear equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) These are sets of equations that have a number of variables.  In general, if you have as many equations as variables, you expect a unique solution.  Your recent questions indicate a need to understand how to solve these.

Answer (score 1):

Using the given data we have 3 equations:
$$s1*(10+t)=600$$
$$s2*(t)=600$$
$$(s1+s2)*12=600$$
You have **3 equations and 3 variables** which you can solve for $s1,s2$.
$s1$=Speed of first printer
$s2$=Speed of second printer

The $1^{st}$ equation gives us:
$$s1={600\over(10+t)}$$ 
The $2^{nd}$ equation gives us:
$$s2={600\over t}$$
The $3^{rd}$ equation gives us:
$$s1+s2=50$$ 
Hence
$${600\over(10+t)}+{600\over t}=50$$ 
Solving this gives you $t$.

Comment: Would they both equal each other, since they both are equal to 600?

Comment: No.s1 will be less than s2.

Comment: No. The common $600$ is the total number of pages printed. $s_1$ ans $s_2$ are the respective speeds of the printers (in pages per minute), $t$ is the time in minutes it takes the second printer to complete the job. - You might just as well replace the three occurances of $600$ with a $1$ (for "one job") if you agree to measure the speeds $s_1$ and $s_2$ in jobs per minute instead of pages per minute.

Comment: Okay, so do I solve all three equations? And if I do, how would i multiply s1 with t, and s2 with t, if I don't know them?

Comment: Using the first equations, you can express $s_2= \frac{600}t$ and $s_1=\frac{600}{10+t}$. Plug this into the third equation and you have only $t$ left as unknown.